# Travelling from one destination to another

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

This is the problem :

Manish has to travel from A to D changing buses at stops B and C enroute. The maximum waiting time at either stop can be 8 minutes each, but any time of waiting up to 8 minutes is equally likely at both places. He can afford up to 13 minutes of total waiting time if he is to arrive at D on time. What is the probability that Manish will arrive late at D?

I know basics in probality . But I don't know how to approach this problem please help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]This can be interpretted geometrically. The result of waiting is a two-dimensional point $(X,Y)$ in a square $8\times 8$. Only the right upper corner is critical, i.e. $X+Y>13$. This critical set is a triangle. Thus, the result is: 
$$\frac{3\cdot 3/2}{8\cdot8}$$

Answer (score 0):

Minutes of waiting can be ${0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}$, and our favored conditions are $(6,8), (7,7), (7,8), (8,6),(8,7), (8,8)$ and there are $81$ total possibilities.

Then probability of being late = $\frac 6{81}=\frac{2}{27}$.